# Как отсортировать поля в 1 таблице по значениям во 2

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь прикрутить к модулю статей в opencart возможность сортировки по кол-ву комментариев в записи.

Первая таблица этого модуля содержит данные о, собственно, записях, 
Вторая таблица содержит комментарии с указанием id записи (из первой табл.), в которой размещается.
Т.е.
1) oc_blog (blog_id, text, title )
2) oc_blog_comment (blog_id, comment)

Нужно отсортировать посты с учетом кол-ва комментов в каждой.
Подскажите правильный sql запрос.

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `JOIN`, выглядеть он будет приблизительно так:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(o_b_c.blog_id) AS comments_count FROM oc_blog AS o_b
JOIN oc_blog_comment AS o_b_c ON o_b_c.blog_id = o_b.blog_id
ORDER BY o_b.comments_count
```

Comment: Хочу дополнить. Уже существует запрос:
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blog i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id) WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1' AND i.sort_order <> '-1'";

Сортировка по дате, например, осуществляется дополнительным запросом: $sql .= " ORDER BY i.date_added DESC, i.blog_id DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit;

Comment: Я попробовал так:
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog i LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id) LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id) LEFT JOIN 
             " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id) 
             WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' 
             AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'  AND i.status = '1'  AND i.sort_order <> '-1'";

Comment: И выборка строкой
$sql .= " ORDER BY comment DESC, i.blog_id LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit;
По кол-ву комментов стало сортировать. НО. Появилась проблема с сортировкой по дате - даты изменились на 01.01.1970. Что это? )

Comment: В таблице комментариев 3 записи. Получается, при связывании берется за основу даты именно из таблицы комментариев? А пустующие места забивает нулями? Тогда - как сделать так, чтоб даты из таблицы комментариев не замещали даты в основной таблице?

Comment: используйте GROUP BY и точную выборку по полям

Answer (score 0):

в данном запросе у вас нету JOIN с blog_comments. В принципе можете добавить его вот так:

```
$sql = "SELECT *, COUNT(ic.blog_id) AS comments_count FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "blog i LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comments ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id) WHERE id.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND i2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND i.status = '1' AND i.sort_order <> '-1'";
```

Тогда сортировка по кол-во комментариев будет

```
$sql .= " ORDER BY i.comments_count DESC LIMIT " . (int)$start . "," . (int)$limit;
```

Comment: Хм, в таком случае ошибка Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: Unknown column 'i.comment_count' in 'order clause'<br />Error No: 1054

Comment: Вот полный текст ошибки:
Uncaught Exception: Error: Unknown column 'i.comment_count' in 'order clause'&lt;br /&gt;Error No: 1054&lt;br /&gt;SELECT *, COUNT(ic.blog_id) AS comment_count FROM oc_blog i LEFT JOIN oc_blog_description id ON (i.blog_id = id.blog_id) LEFT JOIN oc_blog_to_store i2s ON (i.blog_id = i2s.blog_id) LEFT JOIN oc_blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id) WHERE id.language_id = '1' AND i2s.store_id = '0' AND i.status = '1' AND i.sort_order &lt;&gt; '-1' ORDER BY i.comment_count DESC, i.blog_id LIMIT 0,9 in D:\Server\domains\vomer\system\library\db\mysqli.php:40

Comment: Для наглядности:
http://joxi.ru/l2Z9qRkT8p3bbm
http://joxi.ru/brR9x5ZTQg1a0A

Comment: попрбуйте поменять в ORDER BY i.comment_count на i.comments_count

Comment: Нет, там все верно - в двух местах у меня comment_count.
Такой вопрос - можно ли писать сначала COUNT(ic.blog_id) AS comment_count FROM , а потом лишь давать таблице псевдоним ic? - " . DB_PREFIX . "blog_comment ic ON (i.blog_id = ic.blog_id)

Comment: Конечно можно - sql интерпретируемый язык.